# Predefined Set in Alloy

Tags: alloy, formal-languages

I am trying to learn alloy spec. lang. . I can not find a way out about a question.
My question is related with predefined number of elements.

theater_seat set should have 4 members.
Audience set should have 10 members.

There is a theater which is 4 seats available only. But there are 10 people who want to watch the theater. Only 4 of them can have the seat. The rest will go home back.
I am in trouble.
Could you help me about that please?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is my code :

```
module Example
sig Audiance{
   result: lone Seat
}

some sig Seat {}

pred validassignment {
   '#'Seat=4
   '#'Audiance=10
   all a:Audiance | lone a.result
}

run validassignment
```

**EDIT**

How can I eliminate that problem? (Seating on the same seat)

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to show us what you already did, and pinpoint to where you are stuck exactly.
A vague answer to that vague question would be : think "declaratively".

**EDIT**

Here it doesn't work for two reasons:

**First**, what you wrote is **syntactically wrong**. The cardinality operator is # and **not '#'**.
(I redirect you to there : http://www.monperrus.net/martin/alloy-quick-ref.pdf for a nice overview of the main concepts and associated syntax in Alloy)

**Then**, the default scope when you run a command is 3. Meaning each set defined by a signature will have a cardinality of at most 3.
You need thus in your case to **increase your scope** in order to find relevant instances.

You can specify the number of seats and audiances directly in the scope, as follows :

```
  run validassignment for exactly 4 Seat, exactly 10 Audiance
```

There are still other issues in your model. In its current state, it is possible to have everybody in the audience seating on the same seat. I guess you don't want that to happen.

Good luck

Comment: How can I eliminate that problem? (Seating on the same seat)